# Comparing objects in arrays to find event clashes in a timetable

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, comparison

I have 4 Event objects that would be displayed on a school timetable. I need to retrieve an array of the Events that clash with each other i.e. the start time of one Event is in between the start and end time of another. For the sake of getting the algorithm right first i have used int for the times instead of NSDate.

```
 Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
    event.courseName = @"Maths";
    event.room = @"405";
    event.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:8];
    event.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
    [eventsStore addObject:event];

    Event *event2 = [[Event alloc] init];
    event2.courseName = @"English";
    event2.room = @"510";
    event2.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
    event2.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12];
    [eventsStore addObject:event2];

    Event *event3 = [[Event alloc] init];
    event3.courseName = @"Computing";
    event3.room = @"220";
    event3.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];
    event3.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:14];
    [eventsStore addObject:event3];

    Event *event4 = [[Event alloc] init];
    event4.courseName = @"Sports";
    event4.room = @"000";
    event4.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:13];
    event4.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:15];
    [eventsStore addObject:event4];
```

Here is what i have at the moment to find the clashes:

```
 int clashCounter = 0;
    Event *curEv = nil, *otherEv = nil;
    for(int i = 0; i < [eventsStore count]; i++)
    {

        curEv = [eventsStore objectAtIndex:i];


        for (int j = 0; j < [eventsStore count]; j++)
        {
            if (j!=i && ![curEv.clashList containsObject:otherEv])
            {
                otherEv = [eventsStore objectAtIndex:j];
                if (curEv.startTime < otherEv.endTime && otherEv.startTime < curEv.endTime)
                {
                    clashCounter++;
                    NSLog(@"Clash: %@ clashes with %@", curEv.courseName, otherEv.courseName);
                    [curEv.clashList addObject:otherEv];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Starts by creating two empty Event objects. Will loop through each Event in the eventsStore array, sets curEv to the objectAtIndex. Then loops through each of the eventsStore array objects that are not the curEv and does not have otherEv in its array. (each Event object contains an array called clashList for the Events it clashes with). If theres a clash then add otherEv to curEv.

When i run it i get:

```
ClashTest[3393:134117] Clash: English clashes with Computing
ClashTest[3393:134117] Clash: Computing clashes with English
ClashTest[3393:134117] Clash: Sports clashes with Computing
```

This is showing that the Event clashes are picked up but its storing a duplicate in the first instance(the English clashing with Computing goes both ways). But works as it is supposed to when it comes to the Sports and Computing clash because it only shows this once.

How can i get this working properly? 
Apologies if this is deemed to specific, i've been messing around with this for a couple of weeks and haven't had much like no matter what ever way i try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the second loop to start with j = i+1 (and the first loop to stop at i < [eventsStore count] - 1). You would then go only over elements that are after the one checked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a hash map to store the clashes, define this before your first for loop

```
NSMutableDictionary* clashes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Now when you find the clash (where you are logging it), check if the clash already exists both ways and if not, add it to the clashes dictionary like this (but you should have some unique id for the event, I'll assume it's an int e.g.)

```
NSString* firstHashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", curEv.Id];
NSString* secondHashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", otherEv.Id];

if (([clashes valueForKey:firstHashKey] == nil) && ([clashes valueForKey:secondHashKey] == nil)) {
    clashes[firstHashKey] = @[ curEv, otherEv ];
}
else {
    // It is already added to the clashes dictionary so no need to do it
}
```

Now when you want to print all the clashes you can simply do the following

```
for (NSString* key in clashes.allKeys) {
    NSArray* value = clashes[key];
    Event* firstEvent = value[0];
    Event* secondEvent = value[1];
    NSLog(@"Clash: %@ clashes with %@", firstEvent.name, secondEvent.name);
}
```

Comment: I tried it this way but i still had the same issues where the clashes were repeated multiple times.

Comment: Would you please edit your post and put the new algorithm after you added my code, even if another answer solved your problem but I am pretty sure this works

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is the initialization of otherEvent inside the inner loop...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < [eventsStore count]; j++)
    {
        if (j!=i && ![curEv.clashList containsObject:otherEv]) // <-- look
        {
            // this happens too late to properly check the condition above
            otherEv = [eventsStore objectAtIndex:j];
```

Change it like this...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < [eventsStore count]; j++)
    {
        otherEv = [eventsStore objectAtIndex:j];
        if (j!=i && ![curEv.clashList containsObject:otherEv])
        {
```

and your logic will work.  (Though there are quite a few opportunities for improvement, including shortening this inner loop as suggested above).